# C# 4.0 Console Word MailMerge print error

Tags: c#, printing, ms-word, console, mailmerge

I have an automated MailMerge app that gets data from a SQL database and merges with a Word .dotx then prints.

The mailmerge works fine. When it gets to the print it Opens Word, says there was a print error. But when you click OK, word closes and it prints just fine.

Not sure what the error would be, but the fact I have to click OK would hinder an automated process.

Here is my print code

```
//PRINT
System.Diagnostics.Process print = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
print.StartInfo.FileName = outputFilename;
print.StartInfo.Verb = "PrintTo";
print.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
//DEV
var printerName = @"\\cdssvprn03\9858sam77501";
print.StartInfo.Arguments = printerName;
print.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
print.Start();
print.WaitForExit();
```

Any ideas on where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternate method for background printing...

```
//PRINT LETTER
Console.WriteLine("Printing: " + outputFilename);
string filename = outputFilename;
Application app = new Application();
//DEV/TEST
var printerName = @"\\CDSSVPRN03\9858sam77501";  
app.ActivePrinter = printerName;  
app.Documents.Open(filename);
app.PrintOut();
```